# Matching values within columns

Tags: sed, awk

I have tab-delimited text file containing about more than 1500 rows.

input.txt

```
id   sno1   
EN1  Nucus_2158_mri_1/2_Co_1.0_Le_3104
EN2  Nucus_2158_mri_4/2_Co_1.0_Le_3104
EN3  Nucus_2158_mri_1/2_Co_1.0_Le_3104
EN4  Nucus_2158_mri_1/2_Co_1.0_Le_3106
EN5  Nucus_2158_mri_1/2_Co_1.0_Le_3104
EN6  Nucus_2159_mri_1/2_Co_1.0_Le_3104
```

I want to get exact match within column (sno1) by capturing bracketed values (`Nucus_{2158}_mri_{1/2}_Co_1.0_Le_{3104}`) and print their matching ids list. Any help in awk/sed appreciated.

output.txt

```
Nucus_2158_mri_1/2_Co_1.0_Le_3104 EN1,EN3,EN5
```

Comment: Can you what you mean by the dollar signs better?  Usually the best way to explain such things is: (1) illustrative sample input (2) sample command (3) expected output.  You've got 1 and 3 but are a bit unclear on (2).

Comment: Shouldn't `EN2` be part of the matched list?

Comment: @Thor: no, because it's mri_4, not mri_1 (at least, if I understand correctly).

Comment: Ah, I missed the middle pair of dollar signs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you mean the whole second element is the same in each case, you can use it as the key in an associative array. Here is an `awk` example that relies on that:

```
awk '
/^EN/ {
  if(H[$2] == "")
    H[$2] = $1
  else
    H[$2] = H[$2]","$1
}
END {
  for(key in H)
    print key, H[key]
}' infile
```

Output:

```
Nucus_2158_mri_4/2_Co_1.0_Le_3104 EN2
Nucus_2159_mri_1/2_Co_1.0_Le_3104 EN6
Nucus_2158_mri_1/2_Co_1.0_Le_3104 EN1,EN3,EN5
Nucus_2158_mri_1/2_Co_1.0_Le_3106 EN4
```

Answer (score 3):

pass in the three keys using awk command-line variables(named first, second and third in the example below)

```
awk -v first=2158 -v second=1/2 -v third=3104 
'$2 == "Nucus_"first"_mri_"second"_Co_1.0_Le_"third{print($2,$1)}' input.txt      
| awk '{deleter=$1; gsub(deleter, "", $0);} NR != 1 {deleter=""}{print(deleter" "$0)}' 
| sed -e 's/^\s\+//g' | sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/,/g'
```